# Python 3.3 - syntax error when closing csv files

Tags: python, csv

I was wondering if someone might have the insight as to why my code keeps coming up with syntax error at file.close(). I am unaware that this should be a problem unless python 3.3 has some changes to closing csv files or there is something else which I have overlooked.

```
import csv

Trial = open ('Trial.csv', 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(Trial, delimiter = ',', newline = '')

Trial_New = open ('Trial_test.csv', 'wt')
writer = writer = csv.reader(Trial_New, delimiter = ',', newline = '')

next(reader, None)  
for col in reader:
    Max = [float(max (col[6:9])) for col in reader]
    Min = [float(min (col[9:12])) for col in reader]
    Difference = float (Max) - float(Max)
    Average = Difference/len(col)
    writer.writerow(col[:12] + (str(Min), str(Max), str(Difference), str(Average))

Trial.close()
Trial_New.close()
```

Comment: Full traceback where?

Comment: You should use `with` regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`writer.writerow(col[:12] + (str(Min), str(Max), str(Difference), str(Average))`

should be:

`writer.writerow(col[:12] + (str(Min), str(Max), str(Difference), str(Average)))`

i.e. You are missing a closing ")"

Also, you should be using `with`, as in:

`with open(file_name, 'mode') as file_handle:`

because `with` automatically closes the file for you.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a paren on the previous line of code.